# setting the date format as per customization

Tags: java, date

I need to write the date in this format as shown below..

```
20130509 06:00
```

I am retrieving the date from the database in an date object as shown below

```
 Date s = ((java.util.Date) ((Object[]) object)[++i]);
```

Now please advise how can I set the date in the above format as shown below

```
Date s = ((java.util.Date) ((Object[]) object)[++i]);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");
                Date t = sdf.parse(s);
```

below showing compilation issues as i don't want in string i want it to remain in date type always

Answer (score 2):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date s = ((java.util.Date) ((Object[]) object)[++i]);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");
String date = sdf.format(s);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Ankur, are you sure SimpleDateFormat's parse() method take Date as parameter?? I doubt it.

PS : just to be clear, it doesnt, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @indyaah: you are correct, it was a typing mistake. modified the answer.

Comment: @Ankur please suggest that final outcome should not be of  string type it should be of date type

Comment: @TuntunDfdhflflfff: If you convert the string into Date object then the formatting will be lost

Comment: @indyaah date is of which type it is of date type please advise as rite now i am still getting compilation error

Comment: @TuntunDfdhflflfff : Honestly I couldnt understand your above comment, could you please explain. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the right answer. But this may help someone

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/customize-date-display-format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want String Object from the Date object (i.e. Convert java.util.Date to java.lang.String),

```
Date s = ((java.util.Date) ((Object[]) object)[++i]);
String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm").format(s);
System.out.println(myDate);
```

**Edit 1 :**

I guess you want to truncate Seconds part once you have retrieved the date,
You can either do this in your query or just convert the String back to Date again (which I believe is pretty crude, doing it in query is the best way, IMO).

With above code included,

```
 Date truncatedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm").parse(myDate);
```

**EDIT 2 :** In your code you are trying to parse Date object with SimpleDateFormat's parse method which only take String so it will give compilation error.

HTH.

Comment: Now whats the differnce between 's' and 'truncatedDate' both are same. All the formating is waste.

Comment: Nopes. The fact is when the date is fetched from Database it may be containing Seconds part, so what happens here is that while we convert date to String we truncate seconds part out of it, and parse it again to Date (ie. truncatedDate) which will differ from s object in terms of Seconds part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");
    Date now = new Date();
    String nDate = sdf.format(now);
    System.out.println("New Date:"+nDate);
```

Comment: this is the string I am getting as final which I do not want i want final to be of date type